# Javascript less than overriding other less than conditions?

Tags: javascript, overriding, if-statement

I am struggling here with this code right here. Working on CodeAcademy and I encountered this little thing that puzzles me. As you can see, I first check if the computerChoice is less than or equal to 0.33. Then I check else if the computer choice is less than or equal 0.66, and end it all with the final else statement.

However shouldn't this crash or interfere somehow, cause as you can see, both the else if and the else and the if will set the computerChoice variable to the desired string depending on what the Random number is. But since 0.23 is less than 0.66 just as 0.23 is less than 0.33 both of the if statements should set the variable to there own specific string.

Why does this actually work, when I think it shouldn't. Is this just the way JavaScript does it? The first if statements overrides the upcoming ones?

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice <= 0.33){
    computerChoice = "rock";
}else if(computerChoice <=0.66){
    computerChoice = "paper";
}else{
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Thanks for all hopefully upcoming help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `else if` part will only be evaluated if the `if` condition is false. So there's no conflict, the first matching condition is used when you have a series of `if...else if...else if...else`.

So in the `0.22` case, because

```
if (computerChoice <= 0.33)
```

evaluates `true`, none of the `else if` or `else` conditions is checked. Control enters the block associated with the `if` and sets the variable's value to `"rock"`.

In the `0.44` case (for instance), because the `if` condition evaluates false, the `else if (computerChoice <= 0.66)` is tested — and because it evaluates true, the block associated with *that* gets entered and the variable's value gets set to `"paper"`.

In the case of all values above `0.66`, both of the first two conditions evaluate false and so the block associated with the final `else` is entered and sets the value to `"scissors"`.

Answer (score 1):

The `else` clause of an `if..else` statement **does not execute** if the `if` clause matched.
In other words, one and only one of the code blocks inside `if..else` is ever executed, the rest isn't.

Answer (score 0):

that won't create problem because you use an else in the second statement

```
else if(computerChoice <=0.66){
    computerChoice = "paper";
```

this also implicitly means that computerChoice is > 0.33.
It would create issues in a case like this:

```
if(computerChoice <=0.66){
    computerChoice = "paper";
else if(computerChoice <= 0.33)
    computerChoice = "rock";
```

that's because it'll never enter the else statement as if computerChoice is <= 0.66 it's also always obviously <= 0.33